# Updating document in solr cloud 4.4

Tags: solr4, solrcloud

I have a **solr cloud 4.4** set up with **two shards**.The shards are in two different machine. I have successfully indexed documents using **CloudSolrServer** of **solr client 4.2.0.** However while updating the documents some of the documents are getting updated while others are not getting updated and the exception is "**org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No active slice servicing hash code f02c79de in DocCollection(myindex)={**" where "myindex" is the name of my index. 
The code for updating the documents is as follows:

```
      CloudSolrServer server = new CloudSolrServer("myip:9983");
  server.setDefaultCollection("myindex");
      List<SolrInputDocument> solrInputDocsList = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
      SolrInputDocument solrInputDoc = new SolrInputDocument();

      List<String> servicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
      servicesList.add("hockey1");
      servicesList.add("blogger1");
      Map<String, List<String>> services = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
      services.put("set", servicesList);
      solrInputDoc.addField("services",services);


      solrInputDoc.addField("id",id);

      solrInputDocsList.add(solrInputDoc);

      server.add(solrInputDocsList);
      server.commit();
```

My Question are:
1) When document are indexed how it is decides which document goes to which shard.
2) Why the update for some of the documents are failing.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, check this article
http://searchhub.org/2013/06/13/solr-cloud-document-routing/

The idea is that you can tell SolrCloud to put some documents together by generating the Id field following this pattern
shard_key!document_id

Everything that shares the shard_key will be placed in the same shard

For question 2, I had the same problem and I fixed it by cleaning the configuration Zookeeper had stored

Regards,
Randall Rosales